# Mouse click coordinates relative to element

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, dom-events

I need to get coordinates of a mouse click event relative to the target element. That is, I am looking for `offsetX`, `offsetY`, but I am aware that implementation of these properties across different browsers is very inconsistent.

Most of the solutions I've found involve iterating over the element's parents, adding offsets, etc.

However according to [this website](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/), these coordinates can be easily calculated as follows:

```
var rect    = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect(),
    offsetX = ev.clientX - rect.left,
    offsetY = ev.clientY - rect.top;
```

Is this safe to use across different browsers? Any horror stories I should be aware of?

Note: I don't want to use JQuery or similar for this.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be much problem in latest versions of browsers like Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera, Safari etc. But there might be issues in older version of browser(especially Internet Explorer).

Comment: Yes, 'there might be issues' is the part I am asking about. Are you aware of any specific issues?

Comment: IE Version below 9 are nightmares for me. Also, Firefox version below 15 or 16. But Firefox developers are doing great to achieve integrity of the browser by adding feature & fixing bugs fast. Check IE -9 versions if you need it.